# Unity Serial.ReadLine() issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arduino, serial-port

So I'm having an Arduino send `Serial.print()` out.

I'm having the strangest issue, maybe it's Unity permissions or OS Permissions (Linux)

So here's what happens.

When Unity calls `Serial.ReadLine()`

Unity will wait forever, basically hanging.

Thought it was permissions so I added

```
sudo adduser $USER $(stat --format="%G" /dev/ttyACM0 )
```

in CMD. Now the account on Linux has permissions, same issues arise.

Here's the strangest part, Unity will hang forever until I type this into CMD **while it's hanging**,

```
cat /dev/ttyACM0
```

Unity will now run and say `Resource is being used`

So I close CMD, and now Unity runs perfectly.

Unity reads and writes to the Arduino with no issues from here.

However, I have to go through this process every time I want to run the program from Run Unity -> Run CMD -> Close CMD.

Also, adding `Serial.ReadTimeout = 100;` does not fix the issue.

Unity will run, but will never read and will forever timeout.

Only working solution is what I stated above so far.

```
using System.IO.Ports;

public class PlayerBar : MonoBehaviour
{
    SerialPort stream = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyACM0", 9600);
    void start()
    {
       stream.Open();
       stream.WriteTimeout = 100;
    }
    void Update()
    {
        string value = "default";
        value = stream.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Arduino code

```
Serial.print("Distance-");
Serial.print(distance);
Serial.print("\n");
```

EDIT: something I tried which was interesting.

```
if (stream.BytesToRead > 0)
    {
      Debug.Log("Open");
    }
else
    {
      Debug.Log("Closed");
    }
```

The Arduino is never sending bytes.

Not until I open CMD -> run the line -> close CMD

I think Serial.Open() isn't correctly opening the serial port.

Comment: What are you using for the return character (both receive and send)?  Readline may be looking for wrong return or you may be sending the wrong return.

Comment: it is `serial.print(Value) then serial.print("\n")` I can read from serial perfectly once I open cmd -> run cat /dev/ttyACM0 -> close cmd.

Answer (score 1):

I got some information from

https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=464481.0

apparently `stream.DtrEnable = true;` && `stream.RtsEnable = true;` fixes this issue.

```
SerialPort stream;
void Start()
{
   stream = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyACM0", 9600);
   stream.WriteTimeout = 300;
   stream.ReadTimeout = 5000;
   stream.DtrEnable = true;
   stream.RtsEnable = true;
   stream.Open();
}
```